# PostGIS ST_GeneratePoints returns empty coordinates

Tags: postgis, unit-testing

I'm trying to generate test data using some of the built-in functions in PostGIS (Postgres 15.5, PostGIS 3.4.1). One of the things I need to do is generate a bunch of points within a general area. I'm trying to use `ST_GeneratePoints`, but the geometry returned the same result each time. Once I passed the result to `ST_ToGeoJSON`, I saw that it always returns a multi-point geometry with no coordinates.

I've tried using different seed values and different numbers of points. All produce the same result:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_MakeEnvelope(-110, 30, -80, 70, 4326)::geometry,1));
-- returns
--               st_asgeojson              
-- ----------------------------------------
--  {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[]}

SELECT ST_GeneratePoints(ST_MakeEnvelope(-110, 30, -80, 70, 4326)::geometry,1);
-- returns
--     st_generatepoints      
-- ----------------------------
--  0104000020E610000000000000
```

What am I missing? Something with the SRID? Or something the function shouldn't be asked to do?

#### Update

This seems to be a problem with negative numbers. If I repeat *this* query enough times (modified the max longitude to be 5 instead of -80), it comes up with some points where longitude is 0-5, and some where the coordinates are empty.

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_MakeEnvelope(-110,30,5,70, 4326)::geometry,1));
-- returns
--                            st_asgeojson                           
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------
--  {"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[2.740916854,67.718493606]]}
```

Similarly, if the latitudes are all negative, I get entirely empty results.

```
SELECT ST_GeneratePoints(ST_MakeEnvelope(60,-50,70,-30,4326),1);
```

Is there a different/better way to handle negative values in PostGIS?

Comment: PostGIS releases only go as high as 3.4.1. The "15" is probably the PostgreSQL release. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact PG and PostGIS versions in use.

Comment: @Vince - updated to add the correct postgis version

Comment: Cannot reproduce with PostgreSQL/PostGIS 12.1/3.0.0 - 14.2./3.3.1

Comment: Works for me. Returns `{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[-100.686691221,55.913954099]]}` with PostGIS version 3.4.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I found that an entirely negative range for either lat or long seems to be the problem - updated the question with that new information.

Comment: I cannot reproduce even with `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_MakeEnvelope(60,-50,70,-30,4326),1));`.

Comment: For now, I'm using a custom function. It's not as nice as `ST_GeneratePoints` should be, but it works for my purposes. I'll update this if/when I figure out what was going on.